# Git couldn't find remote ref for a tag or commit hash

Tags: git

I am trying to pull (I also get the same problem with fetch) to a specific tag on a remote branch. I am trying to run:

```
 git pull origin v0.0.2.1
```

Where v0.0.2.1 is the name of my tag. I get this error message:

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref v0.0.2.1
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I get the same error message if I replace "v0.0.2.1" with the hash for that tag or the hash for the commit the tag refers to.

I have checked that the remote does actually have this tag and this commit (in fact I can successfully run the above commands on a different machine that has this repository). I checked that the .git/config files are the same on both of these machines.

The following still works:

```
 git pull origin HEAD
```

Also, I used

```
git ls-remote origin
```

And I get the following (among other things):

```
016d51475640e738b24cce2fb4019649ed81fa6b    refs/tags/v0.0.2.1
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

**I have found a workaround:**
The following works:

```
 git pull origin refs/tags/v0.0.2.1
```

This works for my task, but I would really like to understand more about why this works and the other approach doesn't. If anyone can provide an explanation that would be awesome.

Comment: Is git in the same version on both machines?

Comment: Indeed the git versions are different! Good thinking. The version of git for which this works (on my machine at least) is 1.7.10.4 and it does not work on 1.7.0.4.

Comment: Shot in the dark - do you perhaps have something named v0.0.2.1 in your own repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading the [changelogs](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes) of `git`'s version 1.7.0 to 1.7.9 we can find several entries which might lead to the explanation. The way ref-lookups are done on the remote-side has changed (to speed up things).

This can explain why version 1.7.0 needs `refs/tags/<tagname>` for fetching and 1.7.10 doesn't.